# giving one snippet priority over another

Tags: neovim, plugin-ultisnips

I would like to use two custom snippets whose endings are the same:

```
snippet ah "\aH for ta marbuta" i
\\aH${0}
endsnippet

snippet iyyah "\iyyah" i
\\iyyah${0}
endsnippet
```

How can I tell UltiSnips to prioritize `iyyah` over `ah`? That is, when I write `rūmiyyah` then press `<TAB>`, I want the result to be `rūm\iyyah`, not `rūmiyy\aH`. (Currently what happens when I press `<TAB>` is that NeoVim asks me which of the two snippets I want to use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:h UltiSnips-basic-syntax`, a few paragraphs down,

> A line beginning with the keyword 'priority' sets the priority for all
> snippets defined in the current file after this line. The default priority for
> a file is always 0. When a snippet should be expanded, UltiSnips will collect
> all snippet definitions from all sources that match the trigger and keep only
> the ones with the highest priority. For example, all shipped snippets have a
> priority < 0, so that user defined snippets always overwrite shipped snippets.

By default, all snippets have priority 0.
Therefore, to prioritize `iyyah` over `ah`,

```
priority 1
snippet iyyah "\iyyah" i
\\iyyah${0}
endsnippet
```

Comment: Will that change the priority of just this snippet or all snippets in the file? Or all snippets after this point in the file?

Comment: @AlexRoberts that will change the priority for all snippets after that point. To reset the priority, add a `priority 0` after that snippet,

Comment: That worked -- thank you!